# Extracting certain pattern from log using Java

Tags: java, extract, file-read

I want to extract a piece of information from a  log file. The pattern that I am using is the prompt of the node-name and the command. I want to extract information of the command output and compare them. Consider the sample output as follows

```
    NodeName > command1

    this is the sample output 

    NodeName > command2  

    this is the sample output
```

I have tried the following code.

```
public static void searchcommand( String strLineString) 
    {


             String searchFor = "Nodename> command1";
             String endStr = "Nodename";
             String op="";
             int end=0;
              int len = searchFor.length();
              int result = 0;
              if (len > 0) {  
              int start = strLineString.indexOf(searchFor);
              while(start!=-1){
      end = strLineString.indexOf(endStr,start+len);

              if(end!=-1){
                  op=strLineString.substring(start, end);

              }else{
                  op=strLineString.substring(start, strLineString.length());
              }
              String[] arr = op.split("%%%%%%%"); 
              for (String z : arr) {
                  System.out.println(z);
                }

                  start = strLineString.indexOf(searchFor,start+len);


              }

              }



    }
```

The issue is that the code is too slow to extract the data. Is there any other way to do so?

EDIT 1 
Its a log file which I have read as a string in the above code.

Comment: Do you have the whole log as a string?

Comment: i read the file as a string for the above code.

Comment: How large is such a string? Have you measured what takes time? Reading the log into a string? Finding the start / stop or the split? It is hard to give specific parsing optimizations she your input does not match the code.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String log = "NodeName > command1 \n" + "this is the sample output \n"
                + "NodeName > command2 \n" + "this is the sample output";

        String lines[] = log.split("\\r?\\n");
        boolean record = false;
        String statements = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
            String line = lines[j];         
            if(line.startsWith("NodeName")){

                if(record){
                    //process your statement
                    System.out.println(statements);
                }

                record = !record;
                statements = ""; // Reset statement
                continue;
            }

            if(record){             
                statements += line;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: or to optimize your code, you can remove the searched string from your strLineString variable. At the end where you reassign start, you write strLineString = strLineString.subString(end); start = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

Use a regular expression. Here is one:

```
    final String input = "    NodeName > command1\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    this is the sample output1 \n" +
            "\n" +
            "    NodeName > command2  \n" +
            "\n" +
            "    this is the sample output2";

    final String regex = ".*?NodeName > command(\\d)(.*?)(?=NodeName|\\z)";

    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(input);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2).trim());
    }
```

Output:

```
1
this is the sample output1
2
this is the sample output2
```

So, to break down the regex:

First, it skips all signs until it finds the first "NodeName > command", followed by a number. This number we want to keep, to know which command created the output. Next, we grab all the following signs, until we (using lookahead) find another NodeName, or the end of the input.